# Is it possible to send a request to WCF service in the browser address line?

Tags: c#, wcf

I wrote a WCF service. It works. I know how to publish it, and how to use it from a Windows Phone application by adding a service reference to the project. But my question is: can I somehow send a query and get a response using my browser (typing something like mysite.com/myservice.svc?blablabla... ) or using a command line?

Comment: Have you tried the wcf test client? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks! I used it (as it is by default) for testing wcf service libraries, but didn't know that I can set whatever location of service I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I somehow send a query and get a response using my browser (typing
>   something like mysite.com/myservice.svc?blablabla... )

Yes, but you need to change your service `OperationContract` by giving [UriTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webgetattribute.uritemplate.aspx) like below

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Sub?x={x}&y={y}")]
long Subtract(long x, long y);
```

There are many other tools for testing WCF services [**WCF Test Client(WcfTestClient.exe)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364%28v=vs.100%29.aspx),[**SoapUI**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/) , [**SOA Cleaner**](http://xyrow.com/Home/Free) etc..